# React MUI Autocomplete Store chosen Values

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

im new to React / Typescript. I just want to store the options that a user chose at the Autocomplete component. After that, i'd need to send the chosen values to an API. How do i do this?...
Code:

```
       <Autocomplete multiple id="tags-roles" options={roles} 
                 getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
                 renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField
                  {...params}
                  variant='standard'
                  label="Choose Roles"
                  placeholder='Roles'
                  />
```

I already tried asking ChatGPT and seeing the Autocomplete doc on the MUI page but couldnt find anything

Comment: You tried creating React.useState and using onChange prop and to update it?

Comment: @VladVladov yes, i could save the value like this, but in my case it wasnt any helpful because i need the selected values as a string or smth, when i tried to log the value of the selected options, it says: [object Object]

Comment: can you update your question and provide full code with store and console.log? BTW you can do JSON.stringify(your object) in logging to see the value

Comment: the value returned from the autocomplete might be an object ,access the value from it and store in the state or just store the data in the state and while making the API call , manipulate the value to a string .

Comment: Whenever you see the data print as `[object Object]`, it is because the data you are trying to print is being converted to a string and objects don't natively have a convenient way to do that. Like one of the earlier commentors mentioned, you can use `JSON.stringify(...the object...)` to have a better string output. `JSON.parse(...)` does the opposite, taking that converted string and giving you back the original value. If the autocomplete is handing you back an object, it sounds like these two pieces might provide you what you need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright i got the answere if others are looking for an answere in the future for this case:

```js
 const handleRolesChange = (event: any, value: any) => {
    const uniqueRoles = value.filter((role: any, index: number, self: any[]) => self.findIndex((r) => r.value === role.value) === index);
    setRole(uniqueRoles);
  }
```

```html
<Autocomplete multiple id="tags-roles" options={roles} value={role} onChange={handleRolesChange}
                 getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
                 renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField
                  {...params}
                  variant='standard'
                  label="Choose Roles"
                  placeholder='Roles'
                  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Dig into the [MUI Autocomplete docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/) and you will find examples, play with them and combine them and you will get code like this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-mendel-pf75t8?file=/src/App.js)

Basically, set up your state. Mutate as needed. Then when you are ready grab those values and send them to your API as needed.